# Validação para DropDownList em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, mvc

Estou realizando um projeto, nele estava fazendo um DropDownList que pega os dados do banco e mostra ao usuário. Até certo ponto deu tudo certo, mas falta uma parte de tratamento, ou uma validação, pois toda vez que alguma caixa de texto está em branco, ele para a aplicação e da este erro

> `System.InvalidOperationException: 'O item ViewData que possui a chave 'idCategoria' é do tipo 'System.String', mas precisa ser do tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.'`

Esse erro sempre ocorre quando quando eu passo uma `SelectList` usando uma `ViewBag`

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

Model Produto

```
public class Produto
{
    private ConexaoDB db;

    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 5 caracteres")]
    [Key]
    public string idProduto { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 50 caracteres")]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preço Unitário")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório")]
    public decimal precoUnitario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Categoria")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório")]
    public string idCategoria { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }

 ...

    public List<Categoria> ListarCategoria()
{
    var strQuery = "select idCategoria, nome from categoria";

    using (db = new ConexaoDB())
    {
        var retorno = db.RetornaRegistro(strQuery);
        return ListaDeCategoria(retorno);
    }
}

public List<Categoria> ListaDeCategoria(MySqlDataReader retorno)
{
    var categorias = new List<Categoria>();
    while (retorno.Read())
    {
        var TempCategoria = new Categoria()
        {
            idCategoria = retorno["idCategoria"].ToString(),
            nome = retorno["nome"].ToString()
        };
        categorias.Add(TempCategoria);
    }
    return categorias;
}

...


}
```

ProdutoController

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var objproduto = new Produto();
    var leitor = objproduto.ListarCategoria();
    ViewBag.List = new SelectList(leitor, "idCategoria", "nome");
    return View();
}

// POST: Produto/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Produto produto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var objproduto = new Produto();
        objproduto.InsertProduto(produto);

        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
    return View(produto);
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idCategoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idCategoria, ViewBag.List as SelectList, "-- Selecione a categoria --", new { @required = "required", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCategoria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Porque coloca tudo dentro da mesma classe, a parte do modelo com as operações? quem te ensinou assim? se sabia que isso é errado, pouco produtivo, causa problemas de desempenho (performace), o custo do seu código é alto? Fora do padrão de nomes que também está no estilo errado

Comment: Realmente eu não sabia que era errado, é que comecei a utilizar MVC a pouco tempo, e ainda to um pouco confuso de como utilizá-lo. Estou tentando me aprofundar um pouco mais sobre

Comment: As camadas são separadas, basicamente falando: as entidades/models que represente as informações, outra para operações de banco de dados que utilizam essas entidades ... isso é o basico. Geralmente faculdade ensina errado ...

Comment: Certo, então os Controllers são especialmente para requisições? Os métodos devem ficar nos Controllers?

Comment: Os Controller recebem e retornam operações de requisição pelo Verbo (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) são como semáforos, as operações de banco de dados são camadas ORM, MicroORM, CRUD básico, e as classes que representam por exemplo uma tabela de banco são os modelos lógicos que representam os modelos físicos (tabelas) ... Claro isso é o básico. Cada um tem sua responsabilidade, quando uma classe tem mais do que uma responsabilidade quebra um dos principios da OOP

Comment: Métodos como este (ListarCategoria), onde seria o lugar mais adequado de colocá-lo?

Comment: Em outra classe exemplo `class Dal { public List<Categoria> Lista(){ ...}}`

Comment: esse padrão é repositorio com ORM: http://www.macoratti.net/14/04/mvc_crud.htm apesar que ORM Entity Framework é uma camada repositorio. mas, te mostra a separação

Comment: Essa eu realmente não sabia, fica tudo bem mais organizado limpo, vou dar uma melhor aprofundada em ORM. Realmente a escola não ensina isso

Comment: Como você disse, falta de organização é um dos maiores problemas, e um dos meus erros ocorreu por falta de organização. Já arrumei o erro, e em próximos projetos, começarei a me organizar mais